# Is Java constructor a Method?

Tags: java, constructor

This question is really confusing

A `________` is a *special method* that has the same name as the class and is invoked automatically whenever an object of the class is instantiated.
Answers:

- constructor
- setter
- getter
- static method

I was thinking constructor is the only with the same name as the class, but wait! constructor is not really a method, it differs from method.
So i read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html) article and came to a conclusion that this question is wrongly formatted, am I right?

Comment: The article is a good find and you already have answered your own question, constructor is not a method.

Comment: @NoelM more like a practice for exam. So ya basically for school, but hey I guess this does validates for a good question as future users will find this helpful right?

Comment: A constructor is a method, because it has an entry in the method table of the .class.

Comment: Note that the rest of the question is a dead give-away.  No other method has the name of the class.  No other method is invoked automatically when an instance is created.

Comment: @NoelM is that a bad smell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Constructors` are in fact a special method, that are used to initialize the state of the newly created instance. When you create an instance like:-

```
A obj= new A();
```

Then, the instance of class A is created using `new` keyword, and then the constructor `A()` is invoked on that newly created instance.

**Further from that article that says: -**

> Constructors have one purpose in life: to create an instance of a
>   class.

**No this is wrong**. Constructor don't create instance, its the `new` keyword that does it. And then constructor initializes the state of the instance created as I stated above.

From [`JLS - Section 8.8`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8): -

> Constructors are invoked by class instance creation expressions
>   (§15.9), by the conversions and concatenations caused by the string
>   concatenation operator + (§15.18.1), and by explicit constructor
>   invocations from other constructors (§8.8.7).
>
> Constructors are never invoked by method invocation expressions
>   (§15.12).

Also from [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

> **Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);**
>
> The above statement has three parts (discussed in detail below):
>   
>       **Declaration**: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that 
>   associate a variable name with an object type.
>       **Instantiation**: The new keyword is a Java operator that creates 
>   the object.
>       **Initialization**: The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, 
>   which initializes the new object.

Comment: Hi Rohit, hope you remembered me! :) we had a chat the other time, as usual this does clear up some confusion, what does the actual Java docs say ?

Comment: @noobprogrammer. Yeah I remember.. See I posted it just now.

Comment: But I see that there is no clear cut saying that 'CONSTRUCTOR IS NOT A METHOD'. Oh well the question gave me few little options so I will choose constructor in that case tks for making me realize the truth behind the mystery of constructor. Tks

Comment: "**No this is wrong.**" - Since the `new` operator cannot be used without a constructor, making that distinction is kind of meaningless.

Comment: @StephenC. Yeah, that's true that object creation is a combined task of `new` and the constructor. But constructor is just used to initialize the instance. That's what I wanted to tell

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are special methods. They are distinct from "normal" methods. But they are methods. Look at this:

```
public class A {    
    public A() {
        this(5); // calls A(int)
    }        
    public A(int arg) {
        // ...
    }        
}
```

Comment: 'Look at this' doesn't prove anything. The JLS says itself says that constructor declarations look a bit like method declarations, but it doesn't say they *are,* anywhere.

Comment: So what is your definition of a method? If you look up method in wikipedia, there are 4 kinds of special methods. One of those are constructors. However, the article about constructor states that constructors are different from methods. IMHO a constructor _is_ a method, and this difference just is what makes it special. With 'look at this' I wanted to point out, that even constructors can be called from (Java) code in places where `new` is not directly used (when delegating from one constructor to another). However I have to agree this is not a proof.

Comment: My definition of a method is 'whatever it says in the JLS'. That's the only normative reference. Wikipedia has no standing in the discussion.